# Illuminate Database Query Exception

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel, tinker

I'm trying to insert data into a table using Laravel Tinker and I'm getting the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
> 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection:
> mysql, SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `excerpt`, `body`,
> `updated_at`, `created_at`) values  (My Family Post, Excerpt for my
> post, Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet., 2023-10-18 16:21:36, 2023-10-18
> 16:21:36)).

This is what I tried:

```
use App\Models\Post;
> Post::create([ 'title' => 'My Family Post', 'excerpt' => 'Excerpt for my post', 'body' => 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.', 'slug' => 'my-family-post', 'category_id' => 1]);
```

Comment: Make sure `slug` and `category_id` are in the `fillable` attributes of your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This error means](https://database.guide/5-ways-to-fix-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-value-in-mysql/), that you have one more field `category_id` in your table `posts`, but you did not specify value for this field.
Also, MySql know nothing about situation, that it should put in this field, if this field is not presented in the `insert` statemen.

So, you have 2 options:

1. add field `category_id` into your statement, thomething like this:

   Post::create([ 'title' => 'My Family Post', 'excerpt' => 'Excerpt for my post', 'body' => 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.', 'slug' => 'my-family-post', 'category_id' => 1]**, category_id => null**);
2. [modify structure of table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) `post` and indicate, which value MySQL should put, if this value is not presented.

Comment: I modified the SQL Table like this: ```ALTER TABLE posts
MODIFY COLUMN category_id INT DEFAULT 0;``` ran the code in Laravel Tinker: ```
> Post::create(['title' => 'My Family Post', 'excerpt' => 'Excerpt for my postr'. 'body' => 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.', 'slug' => 'my-family-post', 'category_id' => 1]);``` and got this error:  PARSE ERROR  PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ',' or ']' or ')' in vendor\psy\psysh\src\Exception\ParseErrorException.php on line 38.